# Enable gradle nature on android libgdx project

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a libgdx game. I clicked "disable gradle nature" on the android project and now I can not run gradle on the android project. I cant even see it the gradle option on the menu when I right click the project name. Can someone please help.

Comment: You are asking about eclipse, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found is to add gradle in the nature section in the .project file for eclipse and that works.